# Queue jobs stuck in Azure Devops pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am facing a problem with the agent pools jobs in my Azure DevOps project.

I have the Azure Pipelines agent pool (not self-hosted) which it says it is running 2 jobs and there are also 70 more in queue.

[image]

When I click on the Azure Pipelines agent pool, it appear all the jobs. All the jobs appear with the white circle icon, it means there are not really any jobs running.

[image]

I tried to cancel and delete all of this jobs and, now, when I click any of them, it shows the following message:

[image]

I've tried by upgrading my user permissions in pipelines manage security options, disabling the agents of the azure pipelines agent pool, deleting the azure agent pool and re-adding it... and neither worked for me. It does not changes anything.

I've also seen that some people says that it could be a pipelines delay bug from Azure DevOps, and some of this people get solved this bug by itself after some hours/days, but I need to solve it quickly.

Comment: May i know if the issue is resolved/gone? If it persists, you can follow the options below for a check, the aim is to update the agent pool status or grant a new pool instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I've also seen that some people says that it could be a pipelines delay bug from Azure DevOps, and some of this people get solved this bug by itself after some hours/days, but I need to solve it urgent.

Yes, it could be recovered after some hours/days. But if it persists now, please try below options:

1. purchase another parallel job, after it works(pipeline can grant the agent), delete the job purchased(link [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Piplines-are-stuck-in-queue-and-not-exec/10230454)).
2. If it doesn't work, use rest api [Agents - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to grant the pool status:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?api-version=6.0`

check if the `provisioningState` in response is `Deallocated`. If it's `not`, update the value via below PowerShell script(change the pool id and agent id to yours):

```
Param(
   [string]$organization = "yourorgname",
   [string]$token = "PAT"  
)

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$url="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/distributedtask/pools/9/agents/8?api-version=5.1"

$body = @"
{
    "Id": 8,
    "ProvisioningState": "Deallocated"
}
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Method PATCH
```

If the issue persists, it could be also caused by the `Agent Pool Service (9)` identity was removed from your `[organization]/Security Service Group`. Note the identity number(9) here could be different on your organization.  Please check the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-agent-pool-does-not-assign-an-agent-/10232529) for the details.

**If you need to resolve it urgent**, first option is to raise a support request  via the Azure portal. You need to have an [Azure support plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/) associated with your subscription? Click [here](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Support) to create a support request. please share the build pipeline url and issue details in the support request description.